# Mule 4: Behavior of Batch Job if Mule application crashes/redeploys

Tags: mule, batch-processing, mule-component, mule4

We need to implement following scenario:
1. Scheduler triggers the process every 30 min. 
2. Fetch the data from Salesforce based on timestamp. 
3.Insert all the records into database using Mule batch job.

For this scenario, if the Mule application crashes or stops in between, we need to start it from the scratch again and from not where the mule application stopped.

**Below is the output we are getting while testing in Anypoint Studio:**
If we stop the application in between when the batch is running, the records keep getting inserted into Database even after the processing of fresh records fetched in the query is completed.

e.g. if 1200 records are fetched in the current batch, the actual records inserted in Database are more than 1200 i.e. they are from the previous batch which was stopped in between.

**So the Queries are :**
1. Can this behavior changed using some configuration so that we can discard the unprocessed records in current batch if mule application crashes?
2. What is the significance of "History" tab in Mule Batch component? It has two fields Max Age and Time Unit. However when the values are set, the application fails to deploy with "invalid content found - batch:history"
3. Is there a way to see the records persisted by mule batch job  in file system when application fails?
   like persistent object store can be viewed inside .mule folder in workspace.

Answer (score 0):

From the run config (right-click on the project at the project tree -> Run As -> Mule Application 'CONFIGURE'), set up the application data to be restarted always. (may have to scroll down a bit to see the option)

hope it helps